# How can I tell if an SPField is a rich text box or a normal text box?

Tags: sharepoint

Can anyone tell me how I can find out if an `SPField` object is a rich text box or a normal text box? If it's a rich text box then I want to use the `GetFieldValueAsHtml` otherwise i want to use the `GetFieldValueAsText` methods.  I have looked at `SPField.Type` but I am either blind (very possible) or it just has a `Text` option that represents all Text field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use the [TypeAsString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield_members.aspx) property? Others seem to have had [issues](http://vspug.com/benrobb/2006/12/11/gotcha-in-spfieldtype/) finding the type.

```
string fieldType = spField.TypeAsString;
```

Comment: That doesn't really work. I have found that multi line text boxes are SPFieldType.Note so if the field is this i am using the HTml return otherwise i return thevalue as Text

Answer (score 1):

```
private bool IsRichTextField(SPListItem item, string fieldName)
{
    bool isRichText = false;

    if (item.Fields.ContainsField(fieldName) && item.Fields[fieldName] is SPFieldMultiLineText)
    {
        var multiLineField = item.Fields[fieldName] as SPFieldMultiLineText;
        isRichText = multiLineField.RichText;
    }

    return isRichText;
}
```